# selector WebDriverWait work, WebDriver not work?

Tags: c#, selenium, geckodriver

I have

```cs
using IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

IWebElement webElement1 = webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("li.inline.t-24.t-black.t-normal.break-words")));
```

it work.

but

```
private IWebDriver driver;

public LinkedInController() : base()
{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver("C:\\Users\\MinhPhuc\\Documents\\geckodriver");
}

IWebElement webElement3 = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.t-16.t-black.t-normal.inline-block"));
```

does not work (2).

How to make (2) work?

Comment: What is that `ExpectedConditions.ElementExists()` which makes (1) work? Details please...

Answer (score 0):

You're 1 character away.

Does this work:

```
private IWebDriver driver;

public LinkedInController() : base()
{
    driver = new FirefoxDriver("C:\\Users\\MinhPhuc\\Documents\\geckodriver");
}

IWebElement webElement3 => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li.t-16.t-black.t-normal.inline-block"));
```

The only change is it's a `=>` (lambda operator) for assigning into an element outside of a method.

SeleniumHQ made this change when they moved away from the pagefactory in c#. See [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5752) and [here](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2018/03/deprecating-parts-of-seleniums-net.html) if you want to more about the selenium change history .

Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) if you want to know more about the lambda.